# Product of two absolutely convergent Dirichlet series

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

We have$$(f * g)(n) = \sum_{d \mid n} f(d)g(n/d).$$How do I see that if the two Dirichlet series$$F(s) = \sum_{n =1}^\infty f(n)n^{-s},\text{ }G(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty g(n)n^{-s}$$converge absolutely for $\text{Re}(s) > \sigma_0$, then in the same half-plane, the following equations hold:$$F(s)G(s) = \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)n^{-s}\right)\left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty g(n)n^{-s}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (f * g)(n)n^{-s}?$$

Comment: Are you having trouble seeing why this is the answer you would expect if you ignored all convergence issues, or are you having trouble dealing with the convergence issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need a trick of change of variablies. Notice that 
\begin{align}
F(s)G(s)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f(n)}{n^s}\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{g(m)}{m^s}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{f(n)g(m)}{(mn)^s}
\end{align}
Now we make a change of variables and use indicator functions to remove the constaint. For fixed $n$, let $m'=mn$, then we get
\begin{align}
F(s)G(s)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m'\geq 1:n\ \text{divides}\ m'}\frac{f(n)g(m'/n)}{m'^s}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m'=1}^\infty \frac{f(n)g(m'/n)}{m'^s}1_{n\mid m'}\\
&=\sum_{m'=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f(n)g(m'/n)}{m'^s}1_{n\mid m'}\\
&=\sum_{m'=1}^\infty\sum_{n\mid m'}\frac{f(n)g(m'/n)}{m'^s}\\
&=\sum_{m'=1}^\infty \frac{f*g(m')}{m'^s}.
\end{align}
Here we use the absolutely convergence to interchange the sum and $1_{n\mid m'}$ denotes a function which is $1$ if $n$ divides $m'$ and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(f*g)(n)}{n^s} =
\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^s}\sum_{d\mid n}f(d)g(n/d)
= \sum_{k\geq 1} \sum_{d\geq 1}\frac1{(kd)^s}f(d)g(k) \;.
$$